# Allowing Outbound UDP 123 - Security Implications?

Tags: security, firewall

What are the risks of allowing outbound UDP 123 for an internal server (archive server) to synchronize with the external NTP server. Our internal server always displays incorrect time intervals because it is currently synchronized with our internal NTP server.

Comment: Why not just fix your internal NTP server?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, The archive server is the one with incorrect time display and it is managed by an external company. The have fixed this a couple of times but it keeps losing time so they suggested that they configure their external NTP server to sync with the archive server. My worry is that if i allow outbound UDP 123, would it not mean that the external company can connect to our archive server anytime, because currently for them to connect they have to contact me first.

Comment: Our Internal NTP server sync correctly with other servers except the Archive server that is managed by the external company.